# How many binary numbers of length $n$ can be generated where $n > 7$ and the number either start with $000$ or ends with $111$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**How many binary numbers of length $n$ can be generated where $n > 7$ and the number either start with $000$ or ends with $111$?**

My questions is, can I choose an $n$ randomly? For example, let's say that $n = 8$. Since the first three digits need to be $0$, they can have only one option and the remaining five digits can be $0$s or $1$s meaning that they have two options. The same identity applies for the ending with $111$ case.

**So my guess is,
$2^5+2^5 = 32+32 = 64$**

Is this answer correct? By the way forgive me if I couldn't explained my answer clearly, thanks..

Comment: you forgot to take into consideration, that n>7...

Comment: I did not forget, i chose 8 as n. What do do you mean by that, couldn't see your point :)

Comment: You have counted the numbers  of form $000xy111$ twice.

Comment: Use the fact that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$

Comment: The answer should be given as a function of $n$.

Comment: you have selected one n instead of considering all n greater than 7.

Comment: Those numbers that start with 000 and end with 111 are being counted twice which is something to correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is $$2^{n-3}$$ numbers of length n with 000 at the beginning and 
there is $$2^{n-3}$$ numbers of length n with 111 at the end.
also there is $$2^{n-6}$$ numbers that has both 000 at the beginning and 111 at the end, thus 
the result is $$2 * 2^{n-3} - 2^{n-6} =  15 * 2^{n-6}$$ numbers corresponding your conditions...

Answer (score 1):

**Inclusion/Exclusion:**

The amount of $n$-digit numbers that start with $000$ is $2^{n-3}$

The amount of $n$-digit numbers that end with $111$ is $2^{n-3}$

The amount of $n$-digit numbers that start with $000$ and end with $111$ is $2^{n-6}$

The amount of $n$-digit numbers that start with $000$ or end with $111$ is $2^{n-3}+2^{n-3}-2^{n-6}$